# Pyspark : Deleting columns based on sub set of a string

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe ; which looks like below

```
id   1id  id2  ac1  2ac tre tye
```

I want to delete the columns which contain `"id"` and `"ac"` in them and retain the others

How will I achieve this in pyspark?

Tried "select statements" doesn't work

How should I use regexep on column names here?

Answer (score 1):

Use a simple list comprehension:

- Using Select

  ```
  df.select(*[col(c) for c in df.columns if not("id" in c or "ac" in c)]).show()
  ```
- Using Drop

  ```
  df.drop(*[c for c in df.columns if "id" in c or "ac" in c]).show()
  ```